# (Using only html):html the data is not being submitted through url

Tags: html

The data sent is not being submitted using through url. When I click submit, the url does not have the key value pairs.Note: I have not named anything in action.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Assignment1.19</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Register</h1>
  <form class="" action="#" method="GET">
  <div class="">
    <label for="hi" >First Name:</label>
    <input id="hi" type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Jane" name= "hello" required autofocus>
    <label for="no">Last Name:</label>
    <input id="no" type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Doe"name= "naw" required>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <button type="submit" name="button">Submit</button>
  </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, my bad. I wrote the names and values in the final code. I did type link to action,didnt make a difference. Hence I edited it out for now.

Answer (score 0):

You have two `name` attributes and no `value` values.

You also should have whitespace separating each attribute.

Also, your `action` should point to a URL that handles the request.